# SP2010 Display data from a database with List controls

Tags: development, database

What would be the best/easiest way to retrieve data from a database (Customer info) and display it on a custom page but with the controls of a list: like sort, filter, views and search in the list?

The information is not static so a one-time import to a list is not an option.
An option would be to trigger updates in de database, clear the list and re-import the data but I don't want to have the list displaying the new items tag every time this happens.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Business Connectivity Services (what was Business Data Catalog in SP2007). This allows you to connect to external data (database, web service or custom C# object) and itegrate it as an external list.

More info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518675)

Comment: I can be mistaken but I thought it's not really possible to use BCS in a custom WebTemplate? I need to add this list to a custom WebTemplate based on a teamsite...

Comment: Hmm i dont see the connection between BCS and custom web templates? If you mean you want to provision a list instance, this can be done in a feature. BCS works in team sites also...

Comment: Than I must take a closer look at this again...

Answer (score 0):

My initial reaction is to use a data view web part with a datasource pointed to the external database.  The DVWP can be enabled to have filter and sortability.  With the datasource you can do other things like having a search page to query that data, [here](http://www.philwicklund.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=7379e84f-d131-4c1b-903e-4b12849edf5b&ID=83&Web=8de7cf99-762e-4745-b902-b821d850c07f) is an interesting take on using the form web part to search a DVWP.  It can easily be adapted for 2010.  The DVWP can accept query string parameters, so you can levergae that functionality too.